# How can I access a wallet that failed to sync to Trezor?

Tags: transactions, accounts, xlm, wallets

While setting up my Trezor Model T with an XLM wallet, the Trezor Device went into an "inconsistent" state while sending XLM to activate the wallet. All addresses were verified, problem is that the operation was successful but the verified wallet is completely inaccessible as it improperly synced with the device.

When I plugged the Trezor in again, it was linked with a completely new but officiated public XLM address. Is there any way to have the transaction refunded to the original sender or that I could access the failed public address to send these funds to the new and proper address?